# How to change the colors of a plotly scatter plot

Tags: python, plotly

My question is very simple but I'm stuck. This is my code:

```
fig = px.scatter(df_datos, x="EAD", y="RAR", size="Margen_bruto", color="País", hover_name="Cliente", hover_data={'País':True, 'EAD':':.0f', 'RAR':':.0%', 'Margen_bruto':':.0f'}, size_max=30, trendline='lowess', trendline_color_override='black', trendline_scope='overall', title="dic 2021 - 219 clientes")
```

The 4 colors for the 4 countries are assigned randomly and I want to be able to choose the color for each specific country. How can I do that?

I tried functions like add_traces and markers but I can't manage to do it.

Comment: Can you provide sample data? That is a shortcut to solving your problem.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and learn [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).
In order to get help, you will need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).